# How do I write a constraint in Julia with multiple x, y, z values?

Tags: optimization, constraints, julia

how do I write this constraint properly in Julia?

```
@constraint(adwords, sum(x[i] * priceofhome1[i] for i=1:4)
+ sum(y[i] * priceofhome2 for i=1:4) + sum(z[i] * priceofhome3 for i=1:4) <= 12)
```

I am trying to say that the sum of all of these must be less than or equal to 12.

I tried writing this code various ways

```
@constraint(adwords, sum(x[i] * priceofhome1[i] for i=1:4)
+ sum(y[i] * priceofhome2 for i=1:4) + sum(z[i] * priceofhome3 for i=1:4) <= 12)
```

I get the error below.......

> ERROR: The operators <=, >=, and == can only be used to specify scalar
>   constraints. If you are trying to add a vectorized constraint, use the
>   element-wise dot comparison operators (.<=, .>=, or .==) instead

Comment: You write `priceofhome1[i]` but later write just `priceofhome2` without indexing. I assume `priceofhome2` is also an array. This makes `sum(y[i] * priceofhome2 for i=1:4)` and `sum(z[i] * priceofhome3 for i=1:4)` arrays rather than scalars, hence the error. If so, adding indexing, `sum(y[i] * priceofhome2[i] for i=1:4) + sum(z[i] * priceofhome3[i] for i=1:4)`, should fix this error. I am not a JuMP user, so I do not know if there is any other error.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow !

As suggested by @hckr in his comment, your error is probably that priceofhome2 and 3 might be arrays. Plus, the error Julia gave you supports this idea.

```
@constraint(adwords, sum(x[i]*priceofhome1[i] + y[i]*priceofhome2[i] + 
            z[i]*priceofhome3[i] for i in 1:4) <= 12)
```